# Null Coalescing tem prioridade sobre outros operadores?

Tags: php, lógica, operadores, circuitos-lógicos

Ao usar o operador de Null Coalescing `??` em uma expressão com um valor não-nulo, este valor é retornado, como por exemplo:

```
"foobar" ?? "unbar"        // "foobar"
null ?? "unbar"            // "unbar"
```

E também sabemos que o literal `true` não é nulo, pois:

```
true ?? false              // true
```

nos dá `true` de volta. Mas, ao testar a seguinte expressão:

```
true ?? false == false     // true
```

É obtido `true`. Sabemos que `true ?? false` é `true`, logo a expressão seria `true == false` que seria, em teoria, `false`, mas o contrário é obtido.

É compreensível que o interpretador esteja interpretando `false == false` primeiro, e comparando `true ?? true` logo em seguida. Mas, não era para ele interpretar `true ?? false` primeiro? Qual operador tem prioridade nessa expressão?

Um exemplo prático da reprodução deste problema: https://ideone.com/UAELv0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É fácil verificar, basta olhar a [documentação e ver a tabela de precedência](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php). Ela tem uma prioridade baixa, mas não tanto assim. Especificamente comparando esses dois operadores podemos ver que o `??` com o `==` percebemos que o primeiro tem menos prioridade então será executado depois. Mais ainda a associatividade é da direita, então primeiro ele tenta resolver o que está mais à direta antes de aplicar a ele. Portanto ele faz assim:

```
true ?? (false == false)
```

Porém tem mais uma questão. Pode por o que quiser do lado direito do operador, qualquer valor mesmo, ele não será usado neste caso, porque o lado da esquerda tem um valor válido, então a função do operador é justamente pegar um valor válido e o da esquerda é, portanto:

```
"foobar" ?? false == false
```

dá a *string*. Já:

```
null ?? false == false
```

dá `true`.

Na verdade usar booleano nesses caso só cria confusão, deveria até evitar isso em código normal.

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/srJK6T). E [no **repl.it**](https://replit.com/join/kdtfgvbcfh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Operator/Precedence.php).